# How can I generate a random word in python without using a list or link?

Tags: python

I am trying to generate some random words for a password generator library. I could use a **really** long list of words but I think thats really inefficient. I have also tried using a link like so:

```
import urllib.request

word_url = "http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'}
req = urllib.request.Request(word_url, headers=headers)
response = response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
long_txt = response.read().decode()
words = long_txt.splitlines()
```

However, this is a likely target for a person who would want to attack this. Full comment:

> You're getting your dictionary from the web? That's one of the first places I would attack this, through DNS spoofing or flat-out interception. Don't you have a standard system wordlist (e.g. /usr/share/dict/words) that you could use instead?

The user above suggested using a **standard system wordlist**. How could I use a *standard system wordlist* to generate some words? Or are there better ways to do it? Thanks.

**Edit:**
The above user suggested a standard system worldist however I am on windows. I dont know whether this applies to windows but just so u know.

Comment: Using a standard system worldliest would require just one line of code: `list[random.randint(0, len(list))]`. But as for other ways, try to use a cycle with random chars. Or you need existing words?

Comment: On most Linux systems, there is a "standard system wordlist" in `/usr/share/dict/words`. On Fedora, this is provided by the `words` package. Of course, you need to be careful using a general word list like this, because it's really easy to come up with offensive passwords.

Comment: How could I do this on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You could get a random word from the Moby Dick book (or any other Gutenberg book) as follows:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('gutenberg')
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
import random

moby = set(nltk.Text(gutenberg.words('melville-moby_dick.txt')))
moby = [word.lower() for word in moby if len(word) >2]

random_word = moby[int(random.random()*len(set(moby)))]
```

Note that I've taken the set of `moby` so that all the words are uniformly distributed

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the answer. This does work, but is there anyway of getting rid of ```[nltk_data] Downloading package gutenberg to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\sbenf\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package gutenberg is already up-to-date!``` everytime I run my program?

Comment: I think you have to download `'gutenberg'` only once, you should not have to do that again. So you could leave that line out after you've ran it.

Comment: ah ok i understand. but how could I use this with a library? Say the user imports my library and wants to generate a random word. With your method of doing this, they would see all the donwload stuff everytime they generate a specific password. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: That's a different question, which you might want to ask separately. I don't have experience building libraries, so I don't know how to do that.

Comment: How does this improve over the solution in the question? You're still getting your wordlists from the internet.